# How a file could be deleted?

Tags: linux, files

Some files *(folder of some domain /var/www/vhost/www.example.com)* on our dev server disappeared [it's an ubuntu 14]
I check history, but nothing strange.

So I want to know, otherwise some user do a `rm`, **which are the different way a file could be delete ?**
(it's distant server)

I know I could delete file with ftp connection, so additional question is **how to list all ftp connection with date and ip** ?

Thanks by advance,

Comment: Did a few random file disappear, or did a specific directory disappear?

Comment: This is some website folder, specific directory.
Like it was a human which do it.

Comment: I already check some log, I see request 200 transform to request 404 but thats all .
By the way, there are many many logs in a server. Could you be more specific?

Comment: Perhaps a remote attack?

Comment: Perhaps, but perhaps not...

Answer (score 0):

Check scripts if any executed for housekeeping. If few files are gone, do check if any log rotation script is running.

Else you can use inotify module

```
inotifywait -e delete --timefmt %c --format '%T %_e %w %f' -r -m / >/path/logfile
Setting up watches.  Beware: since -r was given, this may take a while!
Watches established.
Fri Jul 19 11:57:39 2013 DELETE /tmp/ testfiletodelete
Fri Jul 19 11:57:46 2013 DELETE /home/user/ testfiletodelete
```

Please read man page before using it. As including  `--exclude` and some other flags may be useful.